# Way to scroll element in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, js-scrollintoview

Scrolling has always been a problem with selenium automation.

All are welcome to suggest the best and reliable way to scroll element
 on the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Below is the way JavaScript allowed me to resolve the mentioned problem.

```js
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", PassIWebElementOverHere);
```